# Can't select value from dropdown menu

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, bots

[image]So I am getting data from this website [Supreme Website](https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/sweatshirts/dgizur9sp/h1judygnb). A user has already defined the item and color, which was easy to figure out. Now I cannot figure out how to choose the size from the dropdown menu. I have tried this code and other different variants, but they do not seem to work

```
while True:
            try:
                select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="s"]'))
                select.select_by_visible_text("XLarge")
                break
            except (NoSuchElementException):
              wait=WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
              waitBis=wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'time-zone-name')))
              driver.refresh()
```

So that select_by_visible_text is not working. What other suggestions and ways would you try to go here. Thank you.

Comment: Can you share the html using snippet tool via [edit] as I can't view the US site.

Comment: @QHarr Added the snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wait until clickable for parent and then presence of option. You can select options by their `value` attribute

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

#other code
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#s"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#s [value="65382"]'))).click()  #Possibly just [value="65382"]
```

Comment: This one worked. Now I just need to figure out how to use this correctly, because user selects size in the dropdown list, and not the numbers from like in value, so how do I associate that choice from a dropdown with the number that should be input into the selector? So basically make ur code dynamic depending on users' choice. Any thoughts?

Comment: You could try combining the answers given here (mine with supputuri)  e.g. WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//select[@id="s"]//option[normalize-space(.)="XLarge"]'))).click()

Answer (score 0):

Your xpath is not correct. And using webdriverwait will also help.

Try this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_condition as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/jackets/fwpckrdv5/kwam2t7jh?alt=1')
select = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//select[@id="size"]'))))
select.select_by_visible_text('XLarge')
```

Comment: File "C:\Users\artjo\Desktop\Python\tkinter3.py", line 62, in web
    select = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//select[@id="size"]'))))
  File "C:\Users\artjo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: I guess the website loads different based on region. I cannot open the full link you shared, and html source is also different in your screenshot. You mentioned __select_by_visible_text is not working__, did you get any error?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the xpath and click on the option directly.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//select[@id="s"]//option[normalize-space(.)="XLarge"]').click()
```